# Sequelize error handling & code optimization

Tags: sqlite, orm, sequelize.js

My use case is fairly simple, i want to create a new user (username,email,password) but first check that the username/email doesn't exist already.

After checking, i use bcrypt to hash the password and create/store the user in my database

 Here is the code i'm actually using, it works but i think it's a little too complicated so i'm wondering if there is anything i can do to make it a bit more readable/optimized

```
    ipcMain.on('register', (e, newUser) => {
    userRepo.findByUsername(newUser.username).then(
        (user) => {
            if (user)
                e.sender.send('register-failed', "Username already exists!");
            else {
                userRepo.findByEmail(newUser.email).then(
                    (user) => {
                        if (user)
                            e.sender.send('register-failed', "Email already exists!");
                        else {
                            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, saltRounds).then(
                                (hasedPassword) => {
                                    newUser.password = hasedPassword;
                                    userRepo.create(newUser).then(
                                        (user) => {
                                            e.sender.send('register-success', user.get({plain:true}));
                                        },
                                        (error) => {
                                            e.sender.send('register-failed', "Unexpected Error");
                                        }
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        },
        (error) => { e.sender.send('register-failed', "Unexpected Error"); }
    ).catch(error => e.sender.send('register-failed', "Unexpected Error"));
});
```

userRepo module :

```
const db = require('../db.js');

const findByUsername = function (username) {
    return db.models.User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: username
        }
    });
}

const findByEmail = function (email) {
    return db.models.User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
    });
}

const create = function (newUser) {
    return db.models.User.create({
        username: newUser.username,
        email: newUser.email,
        password: newUser.password
    });
}

module.exports = { findByUsername, findByEmail, create }
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
Here's a much more readable code (that may be optimized more, but i find it readable enough)

```
ipcMain.on('register', (e, newUser) => {
Promise.all([userRepo.isUsernameAvailable(newUser.username), userRepo.isEmailAvailable(newUser.email)])
    .then(creation => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, saltRounds).then(
            (hashedPassword) => {
                newUser.password = hashedPassword;
                userRepo.create(newUser).then(
                    (user) => {
                        e.sender.send('register-success', user.get({ plain: true }));
                    }
                ).catch(error => e.sender.send('register-failed', "Unexpected internal error!"))
            }
        ).catch(error => e.sender.send('register-failed', "Unexpected internal error!"));

    }) // User already exists
    .catch((exists) => e.sender.send('register-failed', exists))
```

})

Using the two functions to check availability of username and email

```
async function isUsernameAvailable(username){
    const user = await findByUsername(username);
    if(!user) 
        return Promise.resolve(`Username : "${username}" is available`)
    return Promise.reject(`Username : "${username}" is already taken !`)
}

async function isEmailAvailable(email){
    const user = await findByEmail(email);
    if(!user) 
        return Promise.resolve(`Email : "${email}" is available`)
    return Promise.reject(`Email : "${email}" is already taken !`)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are first checking whether username exists and then checking whether email exists. However, both of them can be checked asynchronously using `Promise.all`.

If anyone of the username or email already exists then you can return an error message.

You have used a promise chain however code looks much cleaner and easy to read if you implement the same code using async-await.

Please refer the below blog for how to implement `Promise.all` using async-await.

https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i managed to get my code cleaner by using promise.all(). Edited my first post

Comment: Glad to hear that!